# Qt 5.1 Serial Comunication using QSerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, x86, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to configure communication with serial-pot using Qt, It's my first application in Qt and according to many threads I wrote this piece of code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QSerialPort>

QSerialPort serial;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent), 
                                         ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    serial.open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);
    serial.setPortName("ttyACM0");
    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial.write("hello");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    serial.close();
}
```

And compiler tells me that device is not open when I build project.

Comment: What is the exact error message and when did you see it?  A screenshot might be helpful, because I highly doubt that the _compiler_ knows anything about devices and whether they are open.

Comment: Check the available serial ports with `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()`. Also you probably need sudo privilege to access the serial device.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you have that device available to open? If this is a *nix system try:

```
ls -l  /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB* ### if USB device or 
ls -l /sys/class/tty/ttyACM* ### if ACM, whatever that is
```

You should get a symbolic link to the devices directory, at least you do on linux.

Also, your code builds fine, however I image it doesn't actually *run* .

In addition, it looks like QSerialPort also has a method (inherited from QioDevice) called "isOpen" that returns a boolean if the device is already open which you should probably be using before both opening and closing to know what the actual state of the device is.

Answer (score 0):

I've opended device using `serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)` and it runs. Thanks for help.